# Translation of "Marone"

Tags: meaning

My son was doing some math exercise and encountered this question:

> „Na, wie war’s?“, ruft meine Mutter aus dem Garten, als ich vom Pilzesammeln komme. Ich breite die Pilze auf dem Tisch aus und rufe zurück: „Mehr als die Hälfte sind Maronen. Drei davon sind leider madig, und diese drei sind mehr als ein Viertel der Maronen.“
>
> „Dann weiß ich, wie viele Pilze du höchstens gesammelt hast“, ruft meine Mutter. Es sind
> (A) 21 (B) 14 (C) 19 (D) 24 (E) 16

As I understand, a child was collecting mushrooms and counting them.  Amongst all of them, more than half are chestnuts, 3 of them are bad, the 3 are more than 1/4 of the chestnuts.  So there are maximal 11 chestnuts because 12/4 equal 3.  What confused me is why counting mushrooms and chestnuts together, the answer is 21.  I let my son ask his teacher, she says it's 21 but did not tell why.

Is there something special in the language part, that makes the math different?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maronen-Röhrling

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: As a native speaker, I would be utterly confused by the implication that someone would (accidentally?) pick up chestnuts while searching for mushrooms. I have never heard of that mushroom type and I don't think it is commonly known (at least by that name?) here in South-Western Germany. Good find!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Maronen are common in the Black Forest. I know them by that name only. But must admit that my teacher wasn't a dialect speaker.

Comment: @Stephie: Interesting. To me, *Maronen* have always been *Esskastanien* and nothing else, and no vendor of *Maronen* that I have come across (on Christmas markets etc.) felt a need to specify they were not offering mushrooms.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper as usual: context is key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the child in the question was picking and counting mushrooms, in this case a special type of edible mushrooms with the full name [*Maronen-Röhrling*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maronen-R%C3%B6hrling), colloquilally often *shortened to **Marone*** amongst mushroom pickers and cooks.

The edible chestnut *[Marone](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edelkastanie)* plays no role in the quiz.

Note that both the mushroom and the tree seed are named for their colour: chestnut-brown.

Comment: So when they say 'Maronen', they are simply a short work for one kind of mushroom, like 'Kuli' for 'Kugelschreiber'.   For me this is more like a language question than a math question.     Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: @TigerHwang exactly. For the math problem, replacing "Pilze" and "Maronen" with another generic / special term pair like "Fish" and "Trout" or "Fruit" and "Apples" would be equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing special, I think you missed only one important word: "höchstens". Which means maximum here.
So the mother does not give the correct number of mushrooms but the maximum number of all the collected mushrooms. So there is still a range of possible solutions left but never more than 21. Only this can derived from the statements given.

Side note: "Marone" in Germany can be both "chestnut" and "bay bolete". In the case of a mushroom it is always "bay bolete". In Austria, Switzerland and Southern Germany the edible chestnut is also known as "Maroni".

Comment: I don't think the math is a problem once one realizes that "Marone" is the mushroom, not the chestnut. See my answer below.

Comment: I don't think so, the OP simply mixed "chestnut" and "bay bolete" but there are still other mushrooms in the quiz not named.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions here:

More than half of the mushrooms X, are chestnut mushrooms, Y.

Three of the chestnut mushrooms, Y, are bad, and those three account for at least one-fourth. Three is more than one fourth of Y, so Y is >= 11.

Plugging back 11 into the previous equation, More than half of the mushrooms X, are chestnut mushrooms, 11, means that X is <= 21. Two other answers, 19 and 14 also work, but the teacher wanted the maximum number, "höchstens".